# Azure ElasticSearch config file and how to add security

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I install the azure plugin for elastic search according to this tutorial. 
[Azure Elastic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/archive-elasticsearch-indices-to-azure-blob-storage-using-the-azure-cloud-plugin/) which is using the template from here

> github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/elasticsearch

After it is deployed, I am able to connect to the kabana from the tutorial link above. If I like to install security for the Azure Elastic Search, how would be possible? 
Furthermore, how do I access the elasticsearch.yaml for the config to further customisation ? 
I tried to access the VM but there are only two ip i can link from the azure portal which is the jumpbox and also the kabana public ip. 
Tried searching the /etc/ folder but didnt get to see the elastic folder after I remote into the server.

Please see this photo for the [IP in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu3ab.png).

I am also very new into ARM (Azure Resource Manager) which now consists multiple nodes of server connected together. It would be best , if someone could help explain how elastic search install into here. As far as I know the master node will proper assign the task to the data node after the request is handled at the client node.

The Elastic version is v2.3.1

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you install use the quickstart to install your cluster (of a single node it sounds like), you are in complete control.

In the case of the template, the jumpbox exists as an access point to pivot into the rest of the cluster. This way you can avoid ever giving your Elasticsearch instances a public IP address, thereby reducing the chance for a driveby attack to take place on your cluster -- because it's never exposed! For what it's worth, this is a pretty common strategy in operational isolation.

So, to get started, you should be able to SSH into the jumpbox, and from there you can use the private address of the Elasticsearch VM to SSH to it, from the jumpbox.

1. SSH into jump box
2. SSH into the rest of the private VMs

Once you have done that, then you should be able to access the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

How do you add security? The only official way to [install security in Elasticsearch is to use the Shield plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/introduction.html). This allows you to encrypt communication to/from Elasticsearch, as well as provide authentication.

Elastic, the company behind Elasticsearch and Kibana, [has its own Azure Quick Start for Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace) that does most of what the template you used does, but it also adds security to it. It may prove to be easier to delete the old cluster and start one from there.

Comment: Thanks for this! I now can able to login to different vm and view the elasticsearch.yml. However, for future, if want to add more data nodes and install more plugin, is it i would need to configure each of the elasticsearch.yml again to adjust their elasticsearch.yml as long as they are in the same cluster.

Comment: With additional VM, we will need to install elasticsearch for that VM and configure it as data nodes? current settings with the template is 3 data nodes, 3 master nodes and 1 client nodes.